# Matplotlib downward curve generation issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot curves like this:

[image]

But the output looks like, all the values are same but still curve going out of control.

[image]

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# m = 8, Gp = 256, Data rate Rb = 1GBPS

x = [-24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6]

# M = 1
x0 = [-24, -22, -20, -18, -16.1]
y0 = [math.pow(10, -1), math.pow(10, -1.7), math.pow(10, -2.9), math.pow(10, -5.8), math.pow(10, -10)]

# M = 4
x1 = [-24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -15.1]
y1 = [math.pow(10, -0.99), math.pow(10, -1.6), math.pow(10, -2.8), math.pow(10, -4.9), math.pow(10, -8), math.pow(10, -10)]

# M = 8

y2 = [math.pow(10, -0.98), math.pow(10, -1.5), math.pow(10, -2.7), math.pow(10, -4), math.pow(10, -6), math.pow(10, -7.9),math.pow(10, -8.6),math.pow(10, -9.1),math.pow(10, -9.5),math.pow(10, -9.6)]

# M = 12
y3 = [math.pow(10, -0.97), math.pow(10, -1.4), math.pow(10, -2.65), math.pow(10, -3.8), math.pow(10, -4.8), math.pow(10, -5.8),math.pow(10, -6),math.pow(10, -6.2),math.pow(10, -6.3),math.pow(10, -6.3)]

# M = 16
y4 = [math.pow(10, -0.96), math.pow(10, -1.4), math.pow(10, -2.1), math.pow(10, -2.5), math.pow(10, -4), math.pow(10, -4.2),math.pow(10, -4.3),math.pow(10, -4.3),math.pow(10, -4.4),math.pow(10, -4.4)]

# M = 32
y5 = [math.pow(10, -0.95), math.pow(10, -1.3), math.pow(10, -1.8), math.pow(10, -2.2), math.pow(10, -2.3), math.pow(10, -2.4),math.pow(10, -2.4),math.pow(10, -2.4),math.pow(10, -2.4),math.pow(10, -2.4)]

# M = 48
y6 = [math.pow(10, -0.94), math.pow(10, -1.2), math.pow(10, -1.7), math.pow(10, -1.85), math.pow(10, -2.0), math.pow(10, -2.0),math.pow(10, -2.0),math.pow(10, -2.0),math.pow(10, -2.0),math.pow(10, -2.0)]

# M = 64
y7 = [math.pow(10, -0.93), math.pow(10, -1.1), math.pow(10, -1.3), math.pow(10, -1.4), math.pow(10, -1.6), math.pow(10, -1.6),math.pow(10, -1.6),math.pow(10, -1.6),math.pow(10, -1.6),math.pow(10, -1.6)]


plt.xlim(right=-6)  # xmax is your value
plt.xlim(left=-24)  # xmin is your value
plt.ylim(top=math.pow(10, 0))  # ymax is your value
plt.ylim(bottom=math.pow(10, -10))  # ymin is your value

plt.plot(x, y7, label="M = 64")
plt.plot(x, y6, label="M = 48")
plt.plot(x, y5, label="M = 32")
plt.plot(x, y4, label="M = 16")
plt.plot(x, y3, label="M = 12")
plt.plot(x, y2, label="M = 8")
plt.plot(x1, y1, label="M = 4")
plt.plot(x0, y0, label="M = 1")

plt.legend()

plt.ylabel('Ber')
plt.xlabel('Average Received Optical intensity')
plt.title("Ber vs Average received optical intensity")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "curve going out of control"?

Comment: i notice your desired curve uses a log scale, but you do not

Comment: Maybe `plt.yscale('log')` to set a log scale on the y-axis?